# Referência está fazendo uma variável mudar o valor de outra

Tags: javascript, referência

Qual motivo o valor retornando no exemplo abaixo é `2` e não `null`?

```js
const Parametros = {
   Produto: {
      valor: null,
      peso: null,
    },
}

const params = Parametros;
params.Produto.valor = 2;

console.log(Parametros.Produto.valor) //2 deveria ser "null" :/
```

Gostaria de uma explicação e se possível, uma solução "ideal" para este problema.

Obs.: Preciso utilizar o `Parametros` como exemplo de estrutura em vários lugares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por que deveria ser null se você atribuiu 2? Quando você fez

```
const params = Parametros
```

você apenas criou outra referência para o mesmo objeto. A referência vai ser const(ante), mas o objeto não. O objeto não sofre "deep copy", ele não é duplicado da forma que você espera.

Um truque para fazer deep copy em Javscript é fazer

```
const params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Parametros))
```

Aí sim você pode manipular "params" à vontade sem que o objeto Parametros seja afetado.

Lembrando que o deep copy via JSON só funciona direito se o objeto foi constituído inteiramente de dados (tipos primitivos número, string, data, etc.) Se houver objetos que não podem ser serializados, vai falhar.

Comment: Entendi, eu estava achando que da forma que eu fiz, o objeto era "copiado". Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: É bem provável que o uso de uma classe seria mais apropriado que clonar o objeto, mas não tem como afirmar sem saber como ele está sendo utilizado.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem problema algum aí, está acontecendo o que o código manda fazer, se não é isso que deseja não mande fazer isso.

Você pega um objeto referenciado em uma variável chamada `Parametros` e aí diz que quer que essa referência seja colocada em uma variável chamada `params`, portanto o mesmo objeto passa ter duas referências. Imagino que entenda o que é referência porque colocou no título.

Então toda vez que muda o objeto referenciado ou por `params` ou por `Parametros` está mudando o mesmo objeto. E claro que toda vez que for acessar esse objeto verá a mudança, não importa quem mudou.

Se não deseja isso, não faça assim. Aí precisaria ver o que deseja.

Pode ser que deseje ter dois objetos diferentes. Quase sempre isso é um erro e pode ser até culpa do desejo errado. Olhando por cima, sem ver contexto maior, não parece que quer ter dois objetos, mas quer um comportamento que não faz sentido.

Se quer mesmo dois objetos precisaria pensar na estratégia de cópia, ainda mais que tem níveis como este. Até que ponto deve copiar o objeto? Tudo? Quer escolher só algumas partes para fazer isso? Começa ficar complicado. E pior, se não pensar bem e achar que é fácil pode errar sem entender porque.

Se realmente quer isso tem uma [pergunta no SOen de como clonar o objeto da forma correta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/221800). Clonando o objeto ele fica independente, mas ainda parece um erro.

Talvez esteja querendo criar um protótipo e está criando um objeto, precisaria definir isso melhor.